# I was writing a quicksort algorithm on python and I am getting an out of index error that I can't solve

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
arr = [5,3,2,6,1,2,3,0,4]


def quicksort(arr,low,high):
    pv = high
    pivot = arr[pv]
    high-=1
    while low<high:
        print("high=",high,"pv=", pv,"low=",low)
        print(arr)
        while arr[low]<pivot:
            low+=1
            print("high=",high,"pv=", pv,"low=",low)
            print(arr)
        while arr[high]>pivot and high>low:
            high-=1
            print("high=",high,"pv=", pv,"low=",low)
            print(arr)
        arr[high],arr[low] = arr[low], arr[high]
    
    
    arr[pv],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[pv]
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)
    return quicksort(arr,high+1,len(arr)-1)



quicksort(arr,0,8)
```

these are the console prints at each step:

```
high= 7 pv= 8 low= 0
[5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
high= 7 pv= 8 low= 0
[0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
high= 7 pv= 8 low= 1
[0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
high= 7 pv= 8 low= 2
[0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
high= 7 pv= 8 low= 3
[0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
high= 6 pv= 8 low= 3
[0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
high= 6 pv= 8 low= 3
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4]
high= 6 pv= 8 low= 4
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4]
high= 6 pv= 8 low= 5
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4]
high= 6 pv= 8 low= 6
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4]
high= 4 pv= 5 low= 0
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
high= 4 pv= 5 low= 1
[0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
high= 4 pv= 5 low= 1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
high= 4 pv= 5 low= 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
high= 3 pv= 5 low= 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
high= 2 pv= 5 low= 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Error message being the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 28, in \<module\>
    quicksort(arr,0,8)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 23, in quicksort
    return quicksort(arr,0,high-1)

  File "\<ipython-input-42-895bbee6df57\>", line 22, in quicksort
    arr\[pv\],arr\[high\] = arr\[high\],arr\[pv\]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well, what is the length of `arr` at that point, what is the value of `high`, and what is the value of `pv`? Did you use a debugger to step through your code yet or do you not yet know how to debug your own code? If not, then I suggest PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: Couple of quick notes: I think your indentation is screwy, only one of those two return statements is reachable, you should add a print before the last set of accesses (those are what is causing the issue), and you should add some different text to your prints so you can tell which is coming from which code point.

Comment: Why does the quicksort function have two consecutive `return` statements?

Comment: Add low<high in all the while statements and remove the return statements.